# webpage div layout issue

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, one 30%, one 70%, with float:left to position them side by side in the webpage. the first div contains some text, a select control and a button. that displays properly. The second 70% width div is a slideshow container. I use javascript to display the slides, which are contained within varying sized divs. The slides have a 50px margin-left and display properly. I have another div within the slideshow container div that contains navigation elements for navigating through the slideshow. I want to position this div below the current slide, offset by 50px left and centre within the slide width.

here's a diagram...

[image: http://www.scproject.biz/design.png]

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: You want to see the page?

Comment: [link](http://www.scproject.biz/puzzlegames.php)

Comment: Please post the codes.

Comment: @Billa The code is not concise. You can view the page source at my link...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/tmqqn9aj/

Kind of hard to tell what you want without seeing your code.

Add a slide container around your slide and then use:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
```

To add the 50px left 'margin'

And add `position: relative` to the 70% width div

Add your nav inside the slide container, leave the width at auto and center align your nav

**Ok, just seen your code..** the problem is you are absolutely positioning .mySlides and so the nav is being pushed to the top of the document as absolute positioning removes any relativity.

Instead, absolutely position your .slideshow-container and add `left: 50px` to it, remove `margin-left: 50px` and `position: absolute;` from .mySlides

Comment: By using the relative position I'm trying to compensate for resizing effects.

Comment: The layout didn't work so well on smaller screen resolutions. Is there another way without absolutely position the .slideshow-container?

Comment: Ok thanks. I have the nav div back in the correct vertical position. The problem now is that the div fills the width of the 70% div and the elements within it are centred within that width. Is there a way to dynamically resize the div when the slide is shown>? My javascript doesn't return a value for the selected slide div width.

Comment: I found a way to resize the nav div in my javascript. Now it's back in the correct position and the two main divs remain relatively positioned. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
}
#leftpart{
  width:30%;
  height:200px;/*remove this*/
  background-color:blue;/*remove this*/
  float:left;
}
#contentpart{
  width:70%;
  height:500px;/*remove this*/
  background-color:red;/*remove this*/
  float:left;
}
#fixeddiv{
  width:30px;
  height:100px;/*remove this*/
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:calc(30% + 5px);
  background-color:cyan;/*remove this*/
  padding:0px;
}
.sidediv{
  margin-top:5px;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;/*remove this*/
  background-color:violet;/*remove this*/
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='leftpart'></div>
  <div id='contentpart'>
    <div id='fixeddiv'>
      <div class='sidediv'></div>
      <div class='sidediv'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```